# Text of the dynamic textField stretches when movieclip is resized?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textfield

Well, i have a movieclip containing a dynamic text-field in it. When movieclip is stretched using transform manager, the text stretches. i am developing a component. Moreover,Event.Resize can not be used as Event.Resize is the Stage event. it does not work for movie-clips and sprite.
Putting it in Event. Enter Frame works but that hangs the whole CMS when this technique is used.
Any helps??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Greensocks transform manager, there are already custom events built in that you can use like this:

```
manager.addEventListener(TransformEvent.SCALE, onScale);
```

in the onScale Function you can set the scale of the TextField as you like, for example keep its original scale:

```
tf.scaleX = 1 / yourMovieClip.scaleX;
tf.scaleY = 1 / yourMovieClip.scaleY;
```

or simply maintain a correct aspect ratio:

```
tf.scaleY = tf.scaleX * yourMovieClip.scaleX / yourMovieClip.scaleY;
```

Comment: Well , i will check that as we have already integrated our system using Senocular Transform manager.Here is the link    http://www.senocular.com/flash/actionscript/?file=ActionScript_3.0/com/senocular/display/TransformTool.as               But you point me to right direction.